# work out f(n), the exact number of unit-time operations each procedure requires as a function of the input size n

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I have these 2 questions - I believe one was posted earlier - but was unanswered. 
I think I have answered 2nd one correctly ...

Any suggestions ?

work out f(n), the exact number of unit-time operations each procedure requires as a
function of the input size n

```
(i) for i<-1 to n do
 for j<-1 to 2n-i do
//a unit cost operation
  ------------------------------ (i) this is i the one i need some help on.
(ii) for i <-1 to n do
 for j <- 2 to (n+i) do
// a unit cost operation

for i: 1 to n do:
 for j: 2 to n + i do:
  unit
```

now, let's say n=1

```
 i=1; j: 2 to 2 = 1 times
 total: 1 units

  n=2

i=1; j: 2 to 3 = 2 times
i=2; j: 2 to 4 = 3 times
 total: 2 + 3 = 5 units

 n=3

i=1; j: 2 to 4 = 4 times
i=2; j: 2 to 5 = 5 times
i=3; j: 2 to 6 = 6 times
total: 4 + 5 + 6 = 10 units

  Pattern being f(n) = n^2 +1 , is that right?
```

Comment: You can use Arithmetic progressions to find f(n), finding out by computing values is not a recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case you mentioned(case (i)) you can use [Arithmetic Progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

In this case as first term=2*n-1 and the last term is n, so sum of all the terms is

S=n/2*(n+2*n-1)=O(n^2)

For the Case II, first term=(n+1-1)=n and last term=(n+n-1)=(2*n-1), so Sum, S is equal to,

S=n/2(first term+last term)=n/2*(n+2*n-1)=O(n^2)

You must have observed that S for both (i) & (ii) are same.

Comment: Thanks - how about the 2nd one ? Did I get that right ? Wondering how to do it using arithmetic progression...

Comment: @Alice Edited the question for case (ii). No the formula can't be derived like the method you opted, many other formulas can be fitted to same value. Also your analysis for case(ii) for n=3 is wrong, calculation mistakes.

Comment: Is it 7,8,9 ? So the total is 25 ? Still struggling applying the arithmatic progression to i)

Comment: it's 3, 4 and 5. Did you know Arithmetic Progression?

Comment: I think I am making a mistake in what it means: for j <- 2 to (n+i) do  ...am not sure what it means,  for j <- 2 to (n+i) do,  I know its a for loop, but don't get the <- arrow, and the 2 to (n+i)...means what ?

Comment: ohh, arrow means assignment operation(as = in C/C++,java), so loop goes from j=2 to j=(3+i).

Comment: Ok, understood - the arithmetic series helped! Yes, I can see that S for both 1 and ii are the same - both are of O(n^2) - most grateful sir!