# first and last terms of a nested loop, sums of arithmetic series starting with non zero index

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, computer-science, integer-arithmetic

I have 2 arithmetic series...

```
(i) for i<- 1 to n do
 for j<- 1 to 2n-i do
//a unit cost operation
```

So the first term is 2n-1, last term is 2n-n = n

```
(ii) for i <- 1 to n do
 for j <- 2 to (n+i) do
// a unit cost operation
```

So similarly, is the first term n+1-1 = n, last term n+n-1 = 2n-1 ?

Where does the minus 1 above come from ? Is this because the index starts with 2 ?

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking, because you haven't formatted your loops the same way.  (And your question is somewhat muddled.)  Could you reformat everything consistently?

Comment: for i <- 1 to n do
 for j <- 2 to (n+i) do
// a unit cost operation

Comment: That's not better.  Edit your post to reformat the first sum to look like the second, and then make sure everything after "so similarly" matches what you've already typed.  `n+1-1` doesn't show up at the moment.

Comment: sorry, i hit return for a new line - but ended up posting instead

Comment: i edited the main window. Is that better ?

Comment: this is actually in reference to a previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374126/work-out-fn-the-exact-number-of-unit-time-operations-each-procedure-requires/23374305?noredirect=1#comment35813486_23374305

Comment: "*Where does the minus 1 above come from?*" Maybe ask the one who put it there, it appears as a proposition of an answer, not a logical conclusion, so it should have an author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23374126/2336725) shows that you are interested in the number of terms in the inner summation.  The loop `for j<- first to last` has `last-first+1` terms (this is easiest to see if you write down some examples with small `last-first`).  So for (1), there are `(2n-i)-(1)+1=2n-i` terms for each `i`.  For (2), there are `(n+i)-(2)+1=n+i-1` terms for each `i`.

---

You add according to the limits that the series specify themselves:

1. when `i=1`, `for j<- 1 to 2n-1`
   when `i=2`, `for j<- 1 to 2n-2`
   . . .
   when `i=n`, `for j<- 1 to 2n-n`
2. when `i=1`, `for j<- 2 to n+1`
   when `i=2`, `for j<- 2 to n+2`
   . . .
   when `i=n`, `for j<- 2 to n+n`

Comment: I am just not getting it! :( where does +1  come in last - first +1 ?

Comment: I think this is puzzling me... last-first+1

Comment: is the j<-2 relevant ? does it make a difference where the start is?

Comment: @Alice I've edited to possibly make it clearer.  I'd recommend writing down some examples and counting them out by hand.